# Fetch data from server (REST API) and set data in a Multiple Select Picker in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using REST API to fetch the data from server and I want to set that data in a multiple select picker in React Native but I am getting an error. Here is my response from the server:

```
[
  {
    "id": 22,
    "name": "Business",
    "slug": "business"
  },
  {
    "id": 17,
    "name": "Digital Marketing",
    "slug": "digital-marketing"
  },
  {
    "id": 23,
    "name": "Fun &amp; Lifestyle",
    "slug": "fun-lifestyle"
  },
  {
    "id": 16,
    "name": "Mobiles",
    "slug": "mobiles"
  }]
```

I want to set the name in the drop down and select multiple value from it. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import MultiSelect from 'react-native-multiple-select';

export default class PostJob extends React.Component {
  state = {
     LangPickerValueHolder: [],
    LangKnown: []
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    fetch('taxonomies/get_taxonomy?taxonomy=project_cat').then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseJson => {
          let langString = responseJson;

          let LangPickerValueHolder = langString.map((name, id) => { return { name, id }; });
          this.setState({
            LangPickerValueHolder
          });
          console.log(langArray);
        }).catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
        });
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MultiSelect
          ref={(component) => { this.multiSelect = component; }}
          onSelectedItemsChange={(value) =>
            this.setState({ LangKnown: value })
          }
          uniqueKey="id"
          items={this.state.langString}
          selectedItems={this.state.LangKnown}
          onChangeInput={ (text) => console.log(text)}
          displayKey = 'name'
          submitButtonText="Submit" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    padding: 8
  }
});
```

But it is showing no item to display.

Comment: Maybe your problem is the render function is called before you set the LangPickerValueHolder array. So, for solving this problem just show the loading until your all data are fetched and set. The show your select component.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your mapping is wrong. It should be `langString.map(item => ({ name: item.name, id: item.id }))`.
2. `items` prop should be `this.state.LangPickerValueHolder`.

Comment: Try the above changes. You are passing `this.state.langString` to prop `items` which is not even set (according to the code you have given)